# Django: during model save, assigning the current user of an object to owner defined as m2m relationship

Tags: django-forms

I'm a Django trainee and would kindly appreciate some help. 
Assigning a user as owner for an object seems to be well documented. However, 
I am trying to assign MORE than one user as the owner of an object and struggling with it.

Using the below code that I found as example in the documentation, seems to apply to a foreignkey definition of owner and does not work during save for owner defined with many to many relationship.

Providing a simplified version of my models.py as follows :

```
Class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ManytoManyField(User, blank=True)
    ...
```

Using an example I found in the django documentation, I have coded in admin.py:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.owner = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Initially, I would like to assign as the owner, the current user who CREATES or ADDS the object ( with the intention of assigning other users later , hence the many to many definition for owner and not a foreign key definition).

What would the equivalent code be for my purpose? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation for [many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)? What have you tried?

Comment: II have tried a few other potential solutions without much success and finally resolved to apply a workaround,  to create a foreign key relationship for the creator of the object and a ManytoMany field for the owner. Creator to store the User who created the object using foreign key relationship. I use the many to many relationship to update the owner's of the object as a manual process as a second step.